# Can I use alternative js template with sprockets?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

From docs I discovered that only ejs and eco officially supported. Can I use other alternative js templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joshua Peek (Sprockets author), answered this question [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/282#issuecomment-3548037).

> Yeah, its pretty easy to roll your own:
>
> Checkout the source for:
>
> https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/eco_template.rb
>   https://github.com/josh/mustache-trimmer/blob/master/lib/tilt/mustache_js_template.rb
>   https://github.com/dharanasoft/haml-sprockets/blob/master/lib/haml-sprockets.rb